# Android: How to build AAR's dependencies into APK?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I have an AAR that has dependencies A and B. Now I'm adding this AAR as part of dependencies of an APK.

So in build.gradle of the APK, i have:

```
compile(name:'MyAAR', ext:'aar')
```

This worked fine and successfully built. But the problem is, when I actually testing the app, I got fatal exception like this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;
        at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.defaultOkHttpClient(OkHttpDownloader.java:31) ...
```

This is because the APK does not have dependency on Picasso, but I used Picasso in my AAR.

So my question is, how do I build the AAR so that when the APK build against the AAR, it will automatically take AAR's dependencies too. I tried `transitive = true`, not working.

Answer (score 0):

The aar file **doens't contain** the transitive dependencies.
Also it doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies. The `transitive=true` is the default and tells Gradle to download the dependencies specified in the pom file. It is the reason because it doesn't work in your case.

In your case you have to add the other dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.

The alternative is to publish the library in a **maven repository** (public or private). Gradle in this case with the pom file is able to download also the dependencies.